# Why does the size/extents of a bounding box of a BoxCollider in Unity show the Z element being double what it is?

Tags: unity

As you can see from the picture below, I fetch the BoxCollider inside CollisionHandler and `Debug.Log()` it to the screen.

In this case, I'm logging the [size](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds-size.html), but the same thing happens with [extents](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds-extents.html). There are 4 logs because I have 4 instances of the object in the scene.

The Z value of the Vector3 is double what it should be, whereas the other values are, for the most part<sup>†</sup>, normal. Also, it seems that each object prints a slightly different value for `extents.z`. Most stay around 1.3, but one gave me 1.07~.

Additionally, it inverts the order for 2 of the objects. I don't know why.

**None of the objects are scaled and all use the exact same values for their collider.**

[image: Screenshot of Unity]

I tried drawing a cube with the same size as the BoxCollider's bounding box, and here's what I got:

[image: Bounding box drawn with Gizmo.DrawBox from the top]

[image: Bounding box drawn with Gizmo.DrawBox from the side]

[image: The bounding box gizmo and the box collider, side-by-side]

[image: The bounding box gizmo and the box collider, side-by-side from the top]

I'm not entirely sure if the misalignment with the Collider in the scene is a sign of a problem or just how `Gizmos.DrawCube()` works. Here's the code that does this:

```
private void OnDrawGizmosSelected() {
    Vector3 origin = coll.bounds.center + transform.TransformDirection(new 
    Vector3(0f, 0f, 0.675323f + skinWidth));
    // The hardcoded number above is Z extent of the box.
    Vector3 direction = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * 2;

    Gizmos.color = Color.red;
    Gizmos.DrawRay(origin, direction);
    Gizmos.DrawCube(origin + direction, coll.bounds.size);
    // Where coll is a reference to the BoxCollider, cached in Awake().
}
```

*Unity version 2019.3.15f1.*

**†** For the X value of 2.286476, it rounded to 2.1 in the 3rd log for some reason. And in the first log, it rounded the doubled value of Z to 2.4 rather than 2.6...

Comment: Do you have a non-uniform scale applied to any parent object in the hierarchy?

Comment: No, I don't. I checked.

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce this problem. Placing a new box collider in my scene and logging its size prints the values set in the inspector, as expected. Can you walk us through the steps needed to reproduce this issue in a new, empty project?

Comment: Yeah, I just tried this on a cube and it worked fine for that. I would assume it's a problem with the model I'm using, but what, exactly, I don't know. I also tried it with another model, and it worked fine there, too...

Comment: I'm not sure how you could reproduce the issue. All I did was throw the model into the scene, add some components (and rename its children), then create an original prefab for use. I did the same thing with another model — even scaled it down from its default of 7ish to 1 — and that one works fine.

Comment: Sounds like you have some legwork to do in eliminating possible differences between this model and cases that work. Can you reproduce the problem in a new project without any components other than the collider and the one that just prints the log? Can you narrow down anything that might be different about the source or construction of this model?

Comment: Perhaps the only thing different here is that the parent (Combine) has its own BoxCollider with a Rigidbody, and the child (Fork) has a BoxCollider *without* a Rigidbody of its own, answering to the parent's. On both the cube and the other model, the BoxCollider came with a neighbor Rigidbody. **(It's the child BoxCollider whose bounds I'm printing.)** But I tried reproducing this on a cube, and again, it worked fine... As for the models, I didn't make them, so I don't really know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113122/discussion-between-verified-tinker-and-dmgregory).